# Dynamically change UIView width based on a number in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` that displays like a bar and its width should change based on a `NSNumber` value displayed on a `UILabel`.

Image below shows the ui[image]

**For instance:** As shown in the image, all 3 orange bars have different values. I need the bar's width should also be different based on the value. The bars with value 14 and 10 should be less in width than the bar with value 18.

Following is the code I wrote but it doesn't work.

```
//Get the value as string
        NSString *countString = cell.numberOfTuneIn.text;
        //MAximum size of the bar
        CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(cell.numberOfTuneIn.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);

        CGRect s = [countString boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.numberOfTuneIn.font} context:nil];

        //set the frame of the bar
        CGRect  rect = cell.barView.frame;
        rect.size.width = s.size.width;
        cell.barView.frame = rect;
```

Can someone please help with:
How do I change the width of the bar based on the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic logic you should follow:

- Get bar number range (e.g. 0-100)
- Get width pixel range (e.g. 0-320)
- Create ratio (e.g. 320 / 100) or 3.2 pixels of width for each 1 you
  increment...

So according to the example above:

- If the bar is 100, it's width is 100 * 3.2 = 320 px width
- If the bar is 50, it's width is 50 * 3.2 = 160 px width

Hope it helped.

```
- (CGFloat)getViewlWidth:(float)labelValue {

    // Setup view bar settings, you can take those settings outside of this method if needed
    int maxLabelValue = 100;
    int viewMaxWidth = 320; // You can make it dynamic according to screen width
    float widthPixelRatio = viewMaxWidth / maxLabelValue;

    // Calculate width 
    CGFloat pixelsResult = labelValue * widthPixelRatio;

    // Return value
    return pixelsResult;
}

// Lets assume that here you get the label value from the server and you called it labelValue
NSString * labelValue = // Value from server

/*
Create UILabel here, showing the value from server
*/

// Get the width of the UIView to be
CGFloat myViewWidth = [self getViewlWidth:[labelValue floatValue]];

/*
Create the UIView here and set its witdh to the result of the CGFloat above (myViewWidth)
*/
```

Comment: dont use absolute values of width... like 320px... use auto layout system and work with ratio of size

Comment: @TomasCejka it is a matter of approach... I do it this way :)

Comment: The 320px is just an example, look at my code, I commented that it can be dynamic... Now it's up to you how you want to make it dynamic. @TomasCejka

Comment: answered before u edit your text with code :-D im glad that we understand

Comment: @s.d. I updated my answer... you cannot expect the answers in Stack Over Flow to work in your code by copying and pasting it. You need to get the basic idea of how to solve the issue you are experiencing and then try to expend your coding skills using creativity and trial and error. Anyway, I tried to get my answer to be as close to what you actually need. Feel free to ask more questions. Also, if you find my answer helpful, please vote and mark as the answer. Thanks.